# convert binary string into base64 first and than into an image

Tags: python, image-processing

I have this code for converting an image into base64 and then into a binary data string. I would like to convert the binary string back into a base64 string and then into the originaL image. Any suggestions? thanks

The code:

```
def pass_image(image_url):
    output = base64.b64encode(requests.get(image_url).content)
    bin = "".join(format(ord(x), "b") for x in base64.decodestring(output))
    return bin
```

Comment: call `base64.decodestring` solely is enough.